# Using arithmetic operations in systemverilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I was trying to create a module for using the sensors that I recently bought. My module works well in simulation , synthesis and implementation. but when I used my module inside the top leveled module, I saw that while synthesizing it, it creates some registers outside it's module. With trial and error I found out that the problem is from a sequence of arithmetic operations.

```
module Sensor_handle_dev1(
    input logic i_clk , i_reset , i_echo,
    output logic o_trg, 
    output logic[7:0] o_distance , sensorNum
    );
    assign sensorNum = 8'b1;
    logic[1:0] IdleState , CatchEchoState , CountState , PackUpState;
    assign IdleState = 2'b00; 
    assign CatchEchoState  = 2'b01; 
    assign CountState  = 2'b10; 
    assign PackUpState = 2'b11; 

    logic next_trg;

    logic[1:0] curState , next_state;
    logic[31:0] l_count , next_count;
    logic[7:0] next_distance; 
    always @( posedge i_clk )
        begin
            if ( i_reset == 1'b1 )
                begin
                    curState <= IdleState;
                    o_trg <= 0;
                    o_distance <= 0;
                    l_count <= 0;
                end
            else
                begin
                    curState <= next_state;
                    l_count <= next_count;
                    o_distance <= next_distance;
                    o_trg <= next_trg;
                end
        end
     always_comb 
            begin
                    next_trg = o_trg; // <-- default value is flopped value
                    next_distance = o_distance; // <-- default value is flopped value
                    next_count = l_count;
                       case(curState)
                             IdleState:
                                begin
                                        next_count = 0;
                                        next_trg = 1;
                                        next_count = 0;
                                        next_distance = 0;
                                        //# trig wait 
                                        next_state = CatchEchoState;
                                end
                           CatchEchoState:
                                begin
                                        next_trg = 0;
                                        if ( i_echo == 1 )
                                        begin
                                            if( l_count < 32'b101101110001101100000000 )
                                                begin  
                                                    next_count = l_count + 1;
                                                    next_state = CatchEchoState;
                                                end
                                            else 
                                                begin
                                                    next_state = IdleState;
                                                end
                                        end
                                        else
                                            begin
                                                next_state = CountState;
                                            end
                                end
                           CountState:
                                begin
                                     // here is the problem
                                    //next_distance =  ((l_count * 68) / 100000) + 1;
                                     next_state = IdleState;
                                end
                           default:
                                next_state = IdleState; 
                           endcase                     

            end

endmodule
```

and the schematic looks like this[image]

how can I implement to evade this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it requires more than one clock to calculate `((l_count * 68) / 100000) + 1`. There should be a warning about this in the synthesis/timing report.

First thing that can be done is reduce the 68/100000 to 17/25000. The synthesizer should have done the same optimization.

Then split the calculation across multiple clocks. Notice in the `CatchEchoState` state when `next_state = CountState;`, `next_count` is not being updated. Some of the distance calculation can be move to this condition.

In the example below I moved the multiplication to the `CatchEchoState` and kept the division in the `CountState`. Check the timing report. If the timing can be meet for partial calc and not the final calc, then include a division of factor of 25000 (ex 40 is a factor of 25000, which then becomes `next_count = (l_count * 17)  / 40;` ... `next_distance =  (l_count / 625) + 1;`). If timing still cannot be meet, consider to increment `next_count` by 17 instead of 1, thereby eliminating the dedicated multiplication logic.

```
...
CatchEchoState:
  begin
    next_trg = 0;
    if ( i_echo == 1 )
      ...
    else
      begin
        next_count = l_count * 17; // <-- partial calc
        next_state = CountState;
      end
  end
CountState:
  begin
    next_distance =  (l_count / 25000) + 1; // <-- final calc
    next_state = IdleState;
  end
...
```

If there is still an issue, then it likely has to do with your top level module or your synthesis configurations.

---

FYI: `o_distance` and `next_distance` need to be at least 24-bits wide to store the maximum unsigned value (assuming max `l_count` value is 11,999,999). Looks like this is what is going on in the screenshot, but it is 8-bits in the provided RTL.

Comment: @Batuhan , I'm curious what the final computational split needed to be. Can you add a comment?